# Android avoid caching

Tags: android, http, caching, networking

```
// http client
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

// Checking http request method type
if (method == POST) {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    // adding post params
    if (params != null) {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    }
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
} else if (method == GET) {
    // appending params to url
    if (params != null) {
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + paramString;
    }
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
}
httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

When I make a server call, it brings data...second time i call it, it brings it cached.. and doesn't call server...
how can i fix this?

i don't want caching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add following HTTP header to your request: `Cache-Control: no-cache`

```
httpGet.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a HTTP header and have :

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

like

```
httpPost.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
httpGet.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

visit 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html

Comment: @user3278732 If you have found this answer as helpful then as per the SO standard, you should appreciate it by either up voting or accepting it.