# Android Http Request - How to disable cache

Tags: android, mysql, caching, android-asynctask, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've developed an app that creates groups for meeting events and works this way:

1. In a listview (that belongs to Fragment A managed by Activity A) the app shows all the groups. This listview is populated by an AsyncTask that makes an **HTTP GET Request** (using **Apache HTTPClient**) to an Restful WS.
2. In this Activity (Activity A) the user can go to another Activity (Activity B) in order to create a new group. To create a new group the app use another AsyncTask that makes an **HTTP PUT Request** to the same WS.
3. After the group's creation, the user is redirected back to the Activity A in order to see the available groups where the new group should be included.

The problem is i'm getting the same list that was presented in the **item 1 from above**. This list only refresh after i click the refresh button a couple of times as if it had some sort of cache.

Solutions that i've tried to avoid cache, unsuccessfully:

1. Using **Transactions** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114209/innodb-inserts-very-slow-and-slowing-down)) to make the inserts faster (i'm doing about 10/20 inserts for group) in the Database (i'm using **InnoDB engine**).
2. Using **SQL_NO_CACHE** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666631/sql-no-cache-does-not-work)) to prevent **MySQL** from place the result in the cache (i'm using this to get the groups list - Activity A).
3. Adding to the **HTTP GET Request** the following header "**Cache-Control: no-cache**" ([source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980684/android-avoid-caching), [source 2](https://wuliangx.wordpress.com/2014/09/21/java-apache-httpclient-disable-cache/)) (i'm using this to get the groups list - Activity A).
4. Clearing the app cache ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977288/clear-application-cache-on-exit-in-android)) whenever the user leaves the Activity A so that when he returns from the Activity B gets the list of groups already with the new group included.

Only works if i try to get the groups list inside Activity B, when the user creates a new group. In this case the WS returns an updated list with the new group included. After that if I return to the Activity A the outdated list is shown again.

How can i prevent use cache in the Activity A?

Thanks

Comment: On which event do you refresh the list in Activity A?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add parameter using the current time in millisecond

something like this :

```
String myurl="http://example.com/myserv.php?getit=labla&currenttime="+System.currentTimeMillis();
```